# Can't find Speechlet Interface in Eclipse

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build an alexa skill, the tutorial sample I'm following references an implementation of the Speechlet interface in Java but for some reason, it's not in the library when i try to access it. How can I work around this?

[SDK Java Tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/handle-requests-sent-by-alexa.html)

[Sample Tutorial](https://github.com/alexa/skill-samples-java/blob/master/helloworld/src/com/amazon/asksdk/helloworld/HelloWorldSpeechlet.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that documentation is out of date with the library; it is written for the SDK v1 but the latest version is v2.

You have a few options:

1. Use v1 of the library and follow that tutorial2.
2. Follow these steps for migrating the various classes used in the tutorial (https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/blob/2.0.x/docs/en/Migrating-To-ASK-SDK-v2-For-Java.rst#request-handlers)
3. Use the v2 version of the hello-world example (https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/tree/2.0.x/samples/helloworld)